# Why my controller action is invoked when user is not authenticated?

Tags: php, security, symfony

Symfony2 Why my controller actoin is invoked when user is not authenticated?

I have action: 
route: `acme/home/list`
with code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/list")
 * @Template()
 */
public function listAction()
    {
        return array(
            'username' => $this->getUser()->getUsername(),
        );
    }
```

and it should be restricted with my security.yml

but i get error when entering it unauthenticated
error: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object in`

here is my security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/acme/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

whhat can be wrong here ? that it doesnt redirect me to loading page ?

Comment: Looking like action could not get the user object. Are you sure you are logged in?

Comment: Show us the routing.yml and the firewalls.

Comment: cleared your cache after you introduced the new acl entry ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am useing the jms translation bundle.
Setting my access_control routes prefixed by ther user locale fixed the prbolem.

here is an example route:

```
- { path: ^/[^/]+/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

just add `/[^/]+` to routes (locale prefix)